# Ask compiler to treat array as array(not pointer) when passing it to a function

Tags: c, arrays

I want to use `sizeof` operator after passing an array to a function but C language is considering it as pointer not an array.

Can we implement a functionality to solve this purpose ?

```
void foo(char array[])
{
    printf("sizeof array = %u\n", sizeof(array)); /* I know array is pointer here */
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[5];
    foo(array);
}
```

Comment: In C, the array arrives at the function as a pointer, whether you define it as `void foo(char array[])` or `void foo(char *array)`. But, you have a type conflict, and, `sizeof(array)` does not give its length.

Comment: Not in C. You can do it with templates in C++.

Comment: ... Which is why you should not have dual tagged. What language are you *really* using?

Comment: In C if you want to pass a copy of the array you can embed it in a `struct`.

Comment: Also `sizeof` is calculated at compile-time only

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev That's not true for VLAs.

Comment: BTW, `sizeof()` yields a value of type `size_t`. The format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%u`.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible and using an array subscript `[]` can be confusing to people not knowing that it will behave as a pointer. The approach that I take is to pass length as another argument or create a struct with pointer and length:

```
struct {
    char * buffer;
    size_t length;
} buffer_t;
```

I don't like the array in the struct or typedef approach as it restricts the data to a fixed size.

Comment: This isn't passing the array and behaves just as though the array and its length are separate parameters for the function.

Comment: True. It actually depends on the semantics of the program. If there is a reusable function processing the passed data, then we don't want it to be restricted to a fixed length. IMO fixed length arrays are generally also constant data with global/static storage. Then we don't need to pass them as argument and hence this problem does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ask the compiler for that. It is not polite to do what you ask it to.

Instead you can add another parameter to your function definition to recieve the size of the array.

```
void foo(char array[], size_t array_size)
{
    printf("sizeof array = %zu\n", array_size);
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[5];
    foo(array, sizeof(array)) ;
}
```

Note: to print size_t use %zu in printf.

Note: to print number of elements, use: sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dedicated typedef, or as said in a remark an embedding struct :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char A5[5];

typedef struct S {
  char a[5];
} S;

void foo(A5 a) /* of course can be "void foo(char a[])" but less clear */
{
  printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(A5), sizeof(a));
}

void bar(S s)
{
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(s.a));
}


int main()
{
  A5 a;
  S s;

  foo(a);
  bar(s);
}
```

Of course in case of the *typedef* you need to use *typeof* on it rather than on the var being a `char*`

But all of that is a kind of hack, C is C ...

Comment: This is a bad hack, I wouln'd do it. Passing a copy of the  array is IMO almost always wrong, especially if the array is big.

Comment: @Jabberwocky if you speak about to pass the struct by value of course it can be by address, this is detail, the problem and subject of the question is not here ^^